# SQLPlus column width

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

`COLUMN Column_name FORMAT a15` works great for columns with string values. When I try to use it for integer column, it gives just ###########. How to change width of column with integer value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To format a numeric column to display 15 digits

```
COLUMN number_column FORMAT 999999999999999
```

Answer (score 0):

Followup to Justin's answer (doc reference):

> To change a NUMBER column's width, use FORMAT followed by an element
>   as specified in Table 12-1, "Number Formats".

[Table 12-1 Number Formats](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12013.htm#BABBDHHE)